# Can a connection between "cone NAT with port restriction" and "symmetric NAT" be established without a third-party?

Tags: nat, port-forwarding, udp

Directly it's impossible, right?

Using an intermediate server isn’t an option because I have a requirement that says that a solution has to exchange lots of data and also be fast.

Although, creating a simple utility, if required, that’d run on both nodes locally and thus facilitates establishing a connection, would be ok.

It'll be a **UDP** connection.

How to do it?

Comment: NAT is one of the problems that IPv6 solved, and is a major reason why some services (*like the XBox gaming network) are IPv6-only.

Comment: @MichaelHampton will using ipv6 alone in this case solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly determined, direct connection is impossible. One needs the help of an external relay reachable from both peers to transfer the data, i.e. [TURN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT) or similar.  If you don't want to rely on a third-party you need to run this relay yourself. If you don't want this either, your problem can not be solved.

Comment: will TCP vs UDP make a difference as of possiblity to establish a connection?

Comment: @mixtouku311: TCP is even worse, i.e. it will not work in cases where UDP still works.

Comment: `one needs the help of an external relay reachable from both peers` --> is this only in the initial stage? thereafter both computers will be able to exchange data directly?

Comment: @mixtouku311: No. The relay is there to transfer all data. I've updated the answer.